# autocron.php in OSTicket

Tags: mysql, events, cron, schedule

Linux Cron Job or MySQL Events doesn't work with my server, So I'm planning to use the Autocron.php in OSTicket.

My requirement is simple I need to call a Stored Procedure, 1st of every month. Everything else the procedure will take care.

Any ways on how to do it without using Linux Cron Job & Mysql Events ?

Comment: Considering the investment of writing a custom cron job handler that will be able to call your PHP file periodically, I would put my weight on to: change host, change server, upgrade server software, change these absurd rules, etc.

Comment: Ye we can change the server or upgrade, But the problem is, This is client specific, They don't have the option to use Cron, I consulted with them, So they said they can't spend money for that right now, So I'm searching for Autocron.